React Native release - FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context (look like index is missing)
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release

I upgraded legacy project that is on react native 67.5 to use android SDK 34.
It work fine in debug but on release I get error in log cat from title.
I checked all similar questions and tried all solutions but app always crash in release.
app/build.gradle:
dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2")
...

gradle-wapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip

Does anybody have some solution for this problem on RN 67.5?

Did you find the solution to this, I'm facing exactly same problem on react-native: 0.67.5, running on debug but error in release?
